# Sending Json to Jira Api

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send a POST request to Jira API

Example Json

```
{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       {
          "key": "BAR"
       },
       "summary": "testttt",
       "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
       "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug"
       },
       "priority" :{
           "name" : "Low"
       }
   }
}
```

I am successfully making a POST request with postman to the API but I am struggling to make this POST request with Laravel.
I made a form in HTML where the admin must write some data like `summary` `description` `issuetype` and `priority`. I am accepting the data in the back end but I am having trouble how can I build such JSON with Laravel.

As you can see here

```
 "issuetype": {
              "name": "Bug"
           }
```

`name` is nested in the `issutype` how can I explicitly create it to be ready to send into the API

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68163261/edit) [the code you already have](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question and show us where you're stuck.

Comment: Just create the appropriate associative array structure. When you encode it as JSON, that will be converted into objects automatically.